# office rule help

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

It's a little complicated what i want to do.

I receive service dispatches in outlook with ticket numbers in the body of the email.

example "store number" "location name" "ticket number"

then I send out service based on this information but I keep this email in my inbox until I receive another computer generated email telling me that that ticket is resolved.  The ticket that tells me the ticket is resolved has the same ticket number as the original dispatch email.

I have a folder for each location number and I manually put the two emails in the corresponding folder when I receive the resolved ticket email.

I need a rule that says, when the resolved ticket comes in BOTH emails containing that ticket number will be organized into the corresponding folder.

is this possible being that the ticket number is always different for each service?  any third party software that can handle this kind of task?  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will probably have to create a macro to do this.  Please see this [guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235852).

Answer (score 0):

in the advanced options of the Rule creations there is an options that searches the body of the email for specific text.  You would have to create a a rule everytime the first email is sent, but will apply to all other emails.

Comment: thanks but that is what i was trying to avoid.  WE get so many emails and the rule would only be useful one time. after the resolved ticket comes in that ticket number is never used again.